# def inside while month/week?

Tags: python

I made a game played for 12 months and every week and the problem is the value of the month and week doesn't increase, they're always a constant `1`.

I have functions above my code and if I put this `play_year()` on top it won't work.

```
def play_year():
    month = 1
    week = 1
    while month <= 12:
        print("Month: ", month)
        print("Week: ", week)
        draw()
        play_week()
        week += 1
        if week == 5:
            week -= 4
            month += 1

        if month == 13:
            print("END OF THE YEAR")
play_year()
```

Example of what I want and output,

```
#Expected
Month 2
Week 4
        draw()
        play_week()
Month 3
Week 1

#Output
Month 1
Week 1
        draw()
        play_week()
Month 1
Week 1
```

Thank you.

The other functions:

```
def draw():
    lucky_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 50), 6)
    return lucky_numbers

#TASK 2
def play_week():

    global weeklyRevenue
    people = []

    for a in range(0, 7):
        a = random.randint(50000, 100000)
        people.append(a)

    print("daily people in a week :", people)

    totalpeople = sum(people)
    weeklyRevenue = totalpeople*3
    dropBox = weeklyRevenue*(45/100)
    weeklyRevenue = weeklyRevenue*(55/100)
    played_tickets = []

    for i in range(totalpeople):
        n = random.sample(range(1, 50), 6)
        played_tickets.append(n)
    print("Number of tickets: ", len(played_tickets))
    print(f"DropBox: ",f"{dropBox:.2f} liras.")
    print(f"Weekly revenue: ",f"{weeklyRevenue:.2f} liras.")
    decide_winners(played_tickets)
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong because It is working on my Python interpreter.  ([Example](https://onlinegdb.com/UFPPLmNdK))

Comment: Are you calling `play_year` inside of either `draw` or `play_week` by any chance? This code works fine without those two functions.

Comment: Can you show us your `play_week` and `draw` functions?

Comment: @LakshyaRaj sure.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes there was one, I deleted it now it works as I wanted, thank you so much! and thanks all